# Neo4j cypher: can I use a scalar function as index expression?

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4j 1.9.2 and I'd like to search an index given a parameter found inside the same cypher query, something like:

```
START x=node:x_idx(p='abc'), y=node:y_idx(id:{ID(x)})
RETURN y
```

It is possible? I can't make it work using a WITH clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't use expressions in index lookups at all.